# Multi-dimentional objects having multi-dimentional groups with keys php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have lists of cities with areas, streets and address but I need to group them as nested objects by grouping them with if have same names.

I have objects of multiple cities with details as below:

```
{
    "City": [
        {
            "area": "some name",
            "colony": "some name",
            "street": "some name",
            "home": "some name"
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to group these details as multidimentional objects in multidimentional objects.

### Final Result

```
{
    "City": [
        {
            "area": [
                {
                    "colony": [
                        {
                            "street": [
                                {
                                    "home": "my-home"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Shall we do that in fortran77 or do you prefer another language ... ?

Comment: $array = array();      foreach ($data as $element) {       $array[$element['city']][] = [ 'area' => $element['colony'], 'name' => $element['apartment_number'];  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue. But anyhow, thanks for your efforts. Solution:

```
$city = $jsonObject;
$array1 = array();
foreach ($city as $object => $element) {
    $array[$element['city']][] = [ 'area' => $element['area'], 'colony' => $element['colony'], 'home' => $element['home'];
}
$array2 = array();
foreach ($array1 as $object => $element) {
    foreach ($element as $key => $value) {
        $array1[$object][$value['area']][] = [ 'colony' => $value['colony'], 'home' => $value['home'];
    }
}
$array3 = array();
foreach ($array2 as $object => $element) {
    foreach ($element as $key => $value) {
        foreach ($value as $row => $column) {
            $array3[$object][$key][$column['colony']][] = [ 'home' => $value['home'];
        }
    }
}
```